# Is displaying text in the body improper syntax?

Tags: html

I am attempting to remove a line space between a paragraph and a list, and I found if I take the text out of the paragraph and just put it in the body, it works. I am insure if this is improper syntax or if there is a better way to do this.

Here is what I am doing as of now.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        This is a list:
        <ul>
            <li>Element A</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

And that returns

> This is a list
>
> • Element A

But I am not sure if it is okay to be putting text outside of any kind of element, but this produces the results that I wanted. Is this okay to do?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#flow-content-1 note that "text" is valid content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly valid (however your example is lacking `<head>` and `<title>` elements). Run it through https://validator.w3.org/ to see. You could also remove any margins, padding, or border on your paragraph element that could be causing the spacing as well.